# how to style a datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to style the **DateTimePicker** jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/2795/release

Unfortunately.. there is no documentation on what to use to style it.
If i use datepicker it styles without issue but the datetimepicker it doesnt. How can I apply the styles to the datetimepicker ?

here is a screenshot

as you can see when i hover over the texbox, the datetimepicker works but.. having a lot of trouble figuring out how to style it.

Thank you

Comment: Please, please, please do not use Comic Sans :(

Comment: @BryanRoss http://tinyurl.com/3vmwb9l

Comment: Have you tried using the Jquery UI - Theme Roller? It is a really powerful tool. You can change colors, fonts, sizes and lots of other things with it. Link - http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS style is attached additionally.

Here: http://plugins.jquery.com/files/dark.datetimepicker.zip

Then you can modify it as you wish.

Edit:
Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6cExS/

Comment: Good, and i add a <link href to it.. and how do i apply it to my current code $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thedate").datetimepicker();
  }); 

 <div id="datepicker"></div>

Comment: I've updated answer. Your current code should be:
`$(document).ready(function() { $("#datepicker").datetimepicker(); }); <div id="datepicker"></div>` Notice the ID of `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

For jquery datetimepicker you can use jquery.ui

Comment: The person is asking about datetimepicker, it means he is already using Jquery UI. You could at least tell him that there are different datetimepicker themes or something like that, but your current answer is not helpful whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked to:

> CSS is attached in ZIP file

Place that `.css` file somewhere on your server, and reference it in your html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/css/file" />
```